# How can I prevent user from going back to Login route in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

This is a private route for allowing only authenticated users to navigate to dashboard "/".

The user can still go back to "/login" after successfully authenticated, how can I prevent this using a private route?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router'
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext'


 

export default function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {

    const{ currentUser } = useAuth()
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>{
               return  currentUser? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to ="/login" />
            }}>
        </Route>
    )
}
```

Comment: Maybe just redirect to '/' if the user is logged in

Comment: @NicolasMenettrier thanks for your time. Should I add a new route where I test if currentUser is null and redirect them to "/"?  
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>{
               return  currentUser?  <Redirect to ="/" /> : <Login /> 
            }}>
        </Route>

Comment: Lazy way to do this will be to use your useAuth hook in your Login component, if currentUser is not undefined you redirect to '/'. But maybe there is better implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your login state in a global state, then you are going to put a condition for rendering the login route,

```js
const globalLoginState = true // -> you are logged in

<BrowserRouter>
 <Router>
  { globalLoginState ? (
    <Route exact path"/" component={DummyPageComponent} /> 
   ) : <Route path="signIn" component={DummySignInComponent} />
  }
 </Router>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I think this is gonna work for you